# jdbc sql server connection error on dev server

Tags: java, sql-server, jpa, jdbc, apache-tomee

I am using tomee, JPA and find below the configuration:

tomee.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<tomee>
    <Resource id="dataSource" type="DataSource">
         JdbcDriver com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
         JdbcUrl jdbc:sqlserver://******:1433;databaseName=******
         UserName ******
         Password ******
         JtaManaged true
    </Resource>
</tomee>
```

persistence.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" 
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd" 
             version="1.0">
   <persistence-unit name="app">
      <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
      <jta-data-source>dataSource</jta-data-source>
      <properties>
         <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect"/>
         <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false"/>
         <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="false"/>
      </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

This is working fine on my local. But when I tried to deploy my application to Dev Linux server, I am getting this exception `WARN: HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata : The TCP/IP connection to the host ******, port 1433 has failed. Error: "null. Verify the connection properties. Make sure that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port. Make sure that TCP connections to the port are not blocked by a firewall.".`

The only difference is localhost is windows machine and dev server is Linux machine. As far as I know for this there are no changes required in connection string except the host name.

I also tried with DB server IP address instead of host name. Now server is stuck at this point: `INFO: HHH000130: Instantiating explicit connection provider:org.hibernate.ejb.connection.InjectedDataSourceConnectionProvider`

Please give your suggestions.

Comment: check if you port 1433 open for external conexion

Comment: yes, I am able to connect successfully from my local. The issue is there only on Dev Linux server.

Comment: ping your database server from linux

Comment: I am able to ping the server. Then I tried with IP address instead of host name. Now its stuck at this point: INFO: HHH000130: Instantiating explicit connection provider: org.hibernate.ejb.connection.InjectedDataSourceConnectionProvider

Comment: Also I checked the port with nmap -p 1433 -sT ******, I got this results Nmap scan report for ****** (IP)
Host is up (0.00035s latency).
PORT     STATE SERVICE
1433/tcp open  ms-sql-s

Comment: This sounds like it may be a TCP packet acknowledgment issue.  I've seen this type of issue with JDBC on Sun Solaris 10 VM connecting to a Win2008 Sql Server farm.  The issue we found was that the Solaris box wasn't seeing package ACKs from the Sql Server due to its TCP configuration / ACK window size.  This may not be your issue, but it  everything works great from Windows, but fails on Linux it's likely a network configuration issue.

Comment: Did some searching, and it seems that the error message you are receiving is linked with errors in the url: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16610832/spring-hibernate-sql-server-connection-failing

The fact that it is localhost vs remote is also a factor here, so might not have anything to do with it being linux. I have only one general recommendation, and that is to change jdbc-driver to jtds, http://jtds.sourceforge.net/, for example config see http://openejb.979440.n4.nabble.com/Proposal-TomEE-embedded-documentation-td4663710.html

Comment: @Tobb I tried with jtds and it worked. So I think there might be some issues if we use sql jdbc driver in linux. Thanks.

Comment: Not only in linux, it has issues in windows as well. If one wants to avoid strange problems like this, it is best to stick with jtds over sqljdbc. Glad to hear it worked out :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried with jtds and it worked. So I think there might be some issues if we use sql jdbc driver in linux.

There was one more issue. When I tried with jtds, I got this exception: `java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: net/sourceforge/jtds/jdbc/Driver : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0`. My local JDK was 1.7 and Dev server JDK was 1.6. And I tried to deploy the war generated from my local to Dev server. Once I changed server JDK to 1.7 this issue also got resolved.

Answer (score 0):

There’s a Windows service that runs on the database server called the “SQL Server Browser” that needed to be restarted. The service was listed as running, but it wasn’t responding to queries. As soon as we restarted this service everything started working again. Here’s some more information on this service.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh510203.aspx